# Run modules independently with source dependencies in Android Studio (Intellij?)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am using Android studio but this may be a general Intellij question (I'm used to eclipse). This seems like it should be super simple, but I can't figure it out.

I want to be able to run either module in my project independently, which is from what I understand the purpose of a module. This has worked fine until now when I want to call code from my "app" module in my "testmodule" module. Android Studio lets me import the code I need with no problems until I try to build the module. Then I get the expected "package not found" error. So then I try adding this in my "testmodule" build.gradle:

```
main.java.srcDirs '../app/src/main/java'
```

This causes two package import statements in my "app" module to fail. One of the failing packages is the package defined in my "app" manifest and the other is specified in my "app" build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '../../connectorAPI/trunk/src'
}
```

I also tried to make one module depend on another but from what I've read in stack overflow (and the vague Android Studio error) one module must be a library file. This obviously doesn't work since I want to be able to run either. I would love to just copy the code I need but then I'd need to change both every time in version control, which is a nightmare.

In eclipse all you have to do is right click and link source. I can't imagine this is impossible or even out of the ordinary, so I must be missing something simple... can someone please help me out?

build.gradle testmodule

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.XXXXX.testmodule"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

build.gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += '../../connectorAPI/trunk/src'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    // Add the ArcGIS Android 10.2.5 API
    compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
}
```

Comment: review - https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#CreatingAModule  .if your module is of type libraries then locate it under ./libraries .. settings gradle -> include ':app', '':libraries:myLib' ./app/build.gradle.dependencies -> compile project(':libraries:myLib')

Comment: That's the problem, I want to be able to run both modules so neither one can be a library module.

Comment: well , try locating both modules 'underneath' the 'app' level in the AS project with circular dependencies...

Comment: As far as I can tell that's how I have it set up. When I look at the file structure on windows explorer, the app and testmodule modules are both on the same level one below the project folder

Comment: try removing the dependencies in "build.gradle" and just refer  to the other modules "main" in the respective android.manifest.  if it wont build, then i guess your back to circular dependencies and should read up on gradle.depencies

Comment: I will try that and let you know. Are you thinking the problem is with circular dependencies? This was my initial thought...

Comment: put a framework Main activity up at the app level. put the 2 modules below that.  Make each of the 2 modules build on their own ( without dependent on other module ) . Limit your interfaces to what can be passed thru intents/parcels.. IMO that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late by a few years but here is what I would do : Declare both modules as library, and create another two as application. Then you can easily import the two libriaries while still having two applications, if that is what you want.

As for the duplicate dependency issue that will arise, you can just add an exclude statement in the build.gradle respectively.